# creating environment variable with user-defined name - indirect variable expansion

Tags: bash, shell, indirection

I am trying to create an environment variable in bash script, user will input the name of environment variable to be created and will input its value as well.

this is a hard coded way just to elaborate my question :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello 
export varName="nameX" #
echo $varName 
export "$varName"="val" #here I am trying to create an environment 
#variable  whose name is nameX and assigning it value val
echo $nameX
```

it works fine
it's output is :

```
Hello
nameX
val
```

But, I want a generic code. So I am trying to take input from user the name of variable and its value but I am having trouble in it. I don't know how to echo variable whose name is user-defined

```
echo "enter the environment variable name"
read varName
echo "enter the value to be assigned to env variable"
read value
export "$varName"=$value
```

Now, I don't know how to echo environment variable 
if I do like this :

```
echo "$varName"
```

it outputs the name that user has given to environment variable not the value that is assigned to it. how to echo value in it?

Thanks

Comment: Use indirection: `echo "${!varName}"`.

Comment: Also keep in mind only certain characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` are allowed in variable name but a user can enter anything.

Comment: it's very bad to pass too much power to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get closure: the OP's question boils down to this:

How can I **get the value of a variable whose *name* is stored in *another* variable in bash**?

```
var='value'    # the target variable
varName='var'  # the variable storing $var's *name*
```

gniourf_gniourf provided the solution in a comment:

Use bash's **indirection expansion** feature:

```
echo "${!varName}"  # -> 'value'
```

The `!` preceding `varName` tells bash not to return the value of `$varName`, but the value of the variable whose *name* is the value of `$varName`.
The enclosing curly braces (`{` and `}`) are required, unlike with direct variable references (typically).
See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

<sup>The page above also describes the forms `${!prefix@}` and `${!prefix*}`, which return a *list of variable names* that start with `prefix`.</sup>

---

**`bash 4.3+`** supports a **more flexible** mechanism: **namerefs**, via `declare -n` or, inside functions, `local -n`:

<sup>Note: For the specific use case at hand, indirect expansion is the simpler solution.</sup>

```
var='value'

declare -n varAlias='var'  # $varAlias is now another name for $var

echo "$varAlias" # -> 'value' - same as $var
```

The advantage of this approach is that the nameref is **effectively just an another name for the original variable** (storage location), so **you can also *assign* to the *nameref* to update the *original* variable**:

```
varAlias='new value'  # assign a new value to the nameref

echo "$var" # -> 'new value' - the original variable has been updated
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html

---

**Compatibility note**:

- Indirect expansion and namerefs are NOT POSIX-compliant; a strictly POSIX-compliant shell will have neither feature.
- `ksh` and `zsh` have comparable features, but with different syntax.